# What is the variable for SKU and Product Name in Magento invoices?

Tags: magento-1.7, sales, administration, packing-slip

I am trying to customize Magento Packing Slips and have the requirement to add the product SKU and Product name to the footer column of the Packing Slip but I cannot find the variable that contains this information.
Does anyone know where to find it?

Comment: And if order contains more then one product which of them you want to put in the footer?

Comment: @Tim Each sku contained in the order and the product name...

Comment: What file are you modifying?

Answer (score 3):

It depends which class you're dealing with (Shipment, Invoice, Packaging). For example, if you were modifying the invoice PDF you'd use an the invoice object instance like this:

```
foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) :
    echo $item->getSku();
endforeach;
```

Edit '$invoice' based on your class.

Comment: Thanks for the assitance. I have a strange requirement to merge the pick list into the Packing slip. For example, If an order contains 5 items with x quantity I need to add it to the bottom of the packing sheet...